# I get Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react'] was not found in any of the following sources while my react native project was starting

Tags: react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I upgraded versions of react native and other packages my project. Then I get the error that below image while the project was starting. What should I do ? If you need more detail about other files, I'm able to give you

[image]

`\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build.gradle' line: 10`

[image]